# Linux commands - how to replace every two sequential new lines as new record?

Tags: bash, replace

I have a log file that has the following structure:

1. Record always begins with time data like YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm-ss
2. Then there can be one or multiple lines including empty lines
3. New record begins with exactly two new lines (like \n characters) followed by YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm-ss at the beginning of line

Sample:

```
2022-05-05-14.06.15.041968 some data
that can spread to one line

2022-05-05-14.06.16.036412 some data
that can spread to
two lines

2022-05-05-14.06.17.234123 some data
that can spread to
two lines

or multiple lines with empty new lines
```

I would like to get:

```
2022-05-05-14.06.15.041968 some data that can spread to one line
2022-05-05-14.06.16.036412 some data that can spread to two lines
2022-05-05-14.06.17.234123 some data that can spread to two lines or multiple lines with empty new lines
```

How to solve this problem using Linux commands like sed, awk, tr and similar?

Answer (score 1):

This should get the job done but with limitation that data after datetime of each record should not include any datetime format string

```
sed '/^$/d' your_file_name | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -E 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{6})/\n\1/g' | sed 1d
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting `gawk` script (standard `awk` in most Linux machines):

```
 gawk '{gsub("\n+"," ");gsub("\n","",RT);print $0 "\n"RT}' RS="\n[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-" ORS="" input.txt
```

Results:

```
2022-05-05-14.06.15.041968 some data that can spread to one line 
2022-05-05-14.06.16.036412 some data that can spread to two lines 
2022-05-05-14.06.17.234123 some data that can spread to two lines or multiple lines with empty new lines
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
        {
                if ( $1 ~ /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}+/ ) {
                        printf "\n%s", $0
                } else {
                        if ($1 != "") printf " %s", $0
                }
        }
        END{
                printf "\n"
        }' input_file | sed 1d

2022-05-05-14.06.15.041968 some data that can spread to one line
2022-05-05-14.06.16.036412 some data that can spread to two lines
2022-05-05-14.06.17.234123 some data that can spread to two lines or multiple lines with empty new lines
```